# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'alert' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: javascript, php, html

Есть такой код в php файле, но как итог я всегда получаю ошибку:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'alert' (T_STRING), expecting
> ',' or ';' in ...\result.php on line 36

Насколько я понимаю все из за ковычек "" которые есть и в атрибутах тегах html, но проблема в том что есть кнопка у которой перенаправление с помощью js:

> onclick="window.location.href='/'">

И там как мы можем видеть тоже присутсвуют одинарные ковычки, как можно обойти эту ошибку и вывести все нормально в echo?

```
    <?php
      $msg = !empty($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : 'error';
      if ($msg == 'success'){

        echo "
          <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Произошла ошибка при обработке платежа!</div>
          » Пожалуйста попробуйте позже, если ошибка повторяется, свяжитесь с администратором.
          <br>
          <br>
          <div class="form-wrap text-center">
            <button class="button btnget" onclick="window.location.href='/'">На главную</button>
          </div>";
      };
      ?>
```

Comment: использовать экранирование можно. Можно изначально использовать одинарные кавычки......и в выводе их экранировать. Тогда двойные не придётся экранировать везде ............ https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single  ,  https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double   ну и использовать HEREDOC можно https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: @СергейМишин Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я знаю можно написать просто без кавычек, то есть:

`<button class="button btnget" onclick=window.location.href='/'>На главную</button>`

...и всё должно работать.

```css
.red,
.blue {
  color: #FFF;
  border: none;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.red {
  background: #900;
}

.blue {
  background: #009;
}
```

```html
<button class=red onclick=alert( 'ALERT!')>alert</button>
<button onclick=alert( 'ALERT2!') class=blue>alert</button>
```

Comment: Хм, странно, изнутри комментария не работает. А когда писал код, то работало.